# "A friend of my father" vs. "a friend of my father's" — which one is right? Why?

Tags: nouns, double-possessive

I have seen them both in my reference book, which is written by a native speaker. I wonder why there are two different phrases to describe the same meaning and am looking forward to some reasonable details to explain why this is so.